# Is there an open source Asp.net membership administration GUI (like netwebadmin, but works online)?

Tags: asp.net, sqlmembershipprovider

Visual studio 2005 comes with a project that lets you use the asp.net membership provider to look up, add, edit, and delete users and roles. It unfortunaltly can't be used online, and in order to have an adminiistration area in your site, it appears that you have to code your own admin interface.

Is there an opensource, or free project that has the functionality of netwebadmin, but can be used online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to have a look at this project on codeplex http://www.codeplex.com/AspNetWSAT, which has an admin interface that you can use. I think there are a few other similar ones around too.

Comment: Wow, I had to migrate my tools to VS2013 and now I have 20+ client sites and no way to administer membership?

Answer (score 1):

I have also been searching for a GUI for these tables. Something so common should have an open sources reference to implement.

Here is something my search has uncovered:

http://msadminse.codeplex.com/

This link includes another link to a more "advanced" version. I haven't had much success using this code, but I'm going to probably grab some of the UI elements to use in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of anything that is readily available, although I have a general solution that I have been considering packaging up and making available as a general freebie, but I've found that there isn't much demand as most of the time it is all specific implementations anyway.

Comment: Thanks, Mitchel. I hope that you do decide to make it available. I'm sure it would help me, and lots of other people.

Answer (score 0):

Shame that this project has now been removed from codeplex. There was at one point a plan to refactor it all into controls iirc. If any one has any other ideas, I personally just want a quick and dirty membership admin section.

Comment: That is a shame. I looked into it and apparently the project was abandoned. 

Here is a thread about it for anyone who is interested.
http://forums.asp.net/p/1390061/2969499.aspx